# Django package naming issues

Tags: python, django, naming-conventions

I have developed a backend library, say, `cool_project`. Now I want to build a web interface for it. So I create a Django project. Of course, I want to name it `cool_project`: my mother told me that Hungarian notation is bad and that the name `cool_project` is much better than any of `cool_project_web` etc.

But now I have a collision. As long as I try importing `cool_project` (the backend one) from `django/cool_project/views.py` (the `views.py` of the main Django app) a frontend package is being imported.

Is there any way to import backend project in this case? I tried to add full path to backend package (`sys.path.insert(0, "/home/.../...")`) but it didn't help.

Or maybe there is some well-known naming convention which helps avoiding such collisions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use relative imports like`from .. import cool_project` as long you modules are in a package. I would suggest you to rename your app to something else though. It would create unnecessary complexity

Comment: Unfortunately, but are are not in package while I'm developing it. Actually, I was asking about renaming (and conventions) :) At the moment I decided to use `cool_project_web` for the Django app.

Comment: A lot of packages have similar module names, like all apps in django have views and urls module by convention. Problem occurs when you have such module at root level of your project.Besides you could always use some synonym of cool, or use relative imports as I mentioned earlier

Comment: Please mark my answer correct if you found it of any help